# Allow traffic from 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24

Tags: networking, routing, hyper-v, pfsense, rip

First off, its been years since I've really dove into anything network related so I'll try to explain the best I can and accept I probably messed up somewhere along the way.

My primary network (ISP modem/router) uses 192.168.0.1. On this network, I have a server using 192.168.0.2 hosting Hyper-V. Hyper-V has two switches, WAN (External) and LAN(Internal). I have a VM running PFsense connected to both of these and my WAN connection is using 192.168.0.3 and my LAN is 192.168.1.1.

I then have a few other Hyper-V VMs on the mentioned server using the LAN switch only with IPs 192.168.1.2, and 192.168.1.3. From both of these, I can ping IPs in the 192.168.0.x range but I can't do it vice versa. Even a tracert shows my connection hitting 192.168.1.1 (pfsense LAN) then 192.168.0.1 (ISP modem/router).

On my modem/router, Ive tried setting both static routing and dynamic routing. On my pfsense, I setup RIPv2 and chose my WAN interface  and from my reading, this should do lookups and my modem/router and pfSense see each other.

Im not sure where Im going wrong so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your PFSense VM do NAT between the two networks?

Comment: I do not have NAT configured on the pfsense.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know that this is an answer because Im still not clear how I got it working. I didnt use NAT though on the pfsense.

On my ISP modem/router, I set a static route as follows:

```
Destination IP              Subnet Mask     Gateway IP 
192.168.1.1 (pfSense LAN)   255.255.255.0   192.168.0.3 (pfSense WAN)
```

On my pfSense, I set a Static Route as well:

```
Network                Gateway                         Interface
192.168.0.0/24         WAN_DHCP - 192.168.0.1          WAN
```

If you recall, 192.168.0.1 is my gateway to the ISP modem/router.

I know I tried this setup last night but after putting some pfSense firewall rules in place as well, I can now successfully ping from 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24 and vice versa. Network shares working and I can access my pfSense 192.168.1.1 (LAN connection) from the 192.168.0.0/24 space.

So all's well at this time.